Error executing DDL "alter table appointment_services modify column appointment_id integer not null" via JDBC
I am working on a Spring Boot application with a JPA/Hibernate setup, and I am encountering an error related to the database schema:
Error executing DDL "alter table appointment_services modify column appointment_id integer not null" via JDBC [Referencing column 'appointment_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'FKkv6gwfscv4td54g96ra0p0gn0' are incompatible.] at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final] 
Here is the Appointment entity
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Appointment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Long appointmentId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;

    private String name;
    private String companyName;
    private String email;
    private String phoneNumber;
    private String address;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = ServiceType.class)
    @CollectionTable(name = "appointment_services", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "appointment_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "service_type")
    private Set<ServiceType> serviceTypes;

    @Column(name = "additional_service")
    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> additionalServices;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "appointment")
    private Invoice invoice;

    private String appointmentDate;
    private String completionDate;
    private String status;
}

Here is the service type enum
public enum ServiceType {
    COMMERCIAL,
    RESIDENTIAL,
    KITCHEN_CLEANING,
    BATHROOM_CLEANING,
    WINDOW_CLEANING,
    CARPET_CLEANING,
    UPHOLSTERY_CLEANING,
    MOVE_IN_MOVE_OUT,
    POST_CONSTRUCTION,
    EVENT_CLEANUP,
    FLOOR_CLEANING,
    GREEN_CLEANING,
    DEEP_CLEANING,
    REGULAR_MAINTENANCE,
    SANITIZATION_SERVICES,
    PRESSURE_WASHING,
    GARAGE_CLEANING,
    ATTIC_CLEANING,
    LAUNDRY_SERVICES,
    ORGANIZATION_SERVICES
}

The appointment_services table is being created automatically by Hibernate due to the @ElementCollection annotation on serviceTypes. However, it seems that the appointment_id column in this table is being created with a different type than the appointmentId in the Appointment entity, causing the error.
How can I ensure that the appointment_id column in the appointment_services table is created with the correct type to match the appointmentId column in the Appointment entity? Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
I've tried changing the name of the Appointment entity column from appointment_id to just id
